# Analytic function and derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Show that a smooth complex function $f(z, \bar{z})$ satisfies $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \bar z^{2}}=0$ if and only if $f(z, \bar{z})=\bar{z}g(z)+h(z)$ for some analytic functions $g(z)$ and $h(z)$.

Thought: $(\Leftarrow):$ Follows from taking derivative with respect to $\bar{z}$, since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=g(z)+\bar{z} \frac{ \partial g}{ \partial \bar{z}}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar z}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \bar z^{2}}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}=0$, where I used the fact that $g $ and $h$ are both analytic functions, i.e, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}=0$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar z}=0$.
I have trouble in the other direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \overline z^2} = 0.\qquad(\star)
$$
Set
$$
g(z):=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}.
$$
You know from the assumption $(\star)$ that $g(z)$ is holomorphic (i.e., analytic).
Define
$$
h(z):=f(z)-\overline z g(z).
$$
Compute
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z}=...
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial \bar z}-g(z)-\frac{\partial g }{\partial \bar z} \bar z=0$.

Comment: This means that $h$ is analytic as well. So we are done?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: I see. Thank you, defining $h(z)$ in that way  was tiny bit tricky. :)